How do I make each image in my carousel a clickable link?
Here the images show up in my carousel, but will allow me to click on them and get directed to my other pages. How do I correct this?
<div id="drag-container">
<div id="spin-container">
    <a href="Smokers World Gummie Selection.html"><img src="Hooper Corp. (3).jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="Smokers World Gummie Selection.html"><img src="Shirt1.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="Smokers World Gummie Selection.html"><img src="Shoe Angle.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="Smokers World Gummie Selection.html"><img src="Shoe Side View 2.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="Smokers World Gummie Selection.html"><img src="Shoe Back View.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="Smokers World Gummie Selection.html"><img src="Shoe Top View 1.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="Smokers World Gummie Selection.html"><img src="Me 1.jpg" alt=""></a>



  <p></p>
</div>
<div id="ground"></div>

I tried taking moving the image to the front and still didnt work, tried putting images after my <a herf and removing my angle brackets from the image and that just stopped the images from showing up in my carousel, and tried taking the brackets from aherf listed after the images. Nothing seems to be working. Any ideas would be awesome.

Please provide a proper [mre] of the issue.

You have fundamental errors you could have solved yourself by consistently using the W3C HTML Validator

Check the CSS z-index, and make sure the  tag z-index is bigger as the example below.
#drag-container, #spin-container, img {
   position: relative;
   z-index: 10;
}

a {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 15;
}


It did nothing.....
Any other ideas? I have been looking all over the web for similar issues, but I cant find anything similar.
